# AWS Cloudfront distribution : One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I was using Cloudfront distribution on my domain name registered with Namecheap.
I deleted the existing distribution and create a new one due to some reason which I forgot. I also deleted all the CNAME Record and ALIAS Record on Namecheap.

I have requested a new SSL cert on ACM and the status is Issued and I have entered both naked domain name (abc.com) and sub-domain name ([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)).

Now, when I trying to create a new Cloudfront distribution. I entered both abc.com and [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) under Alternate domain name (CNAME).

I have been searching around google or SO here and most of the answer are some resources already using the CNAME.

How can I search on AWS or use the command line to check what resources are using my CNAME?

I tried **dig** command  and displayed like below
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you already try everything in this guide for this issue from AWS? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cnamealreadyexists-error/

I wonder what the respons is for ``aws cloudfront list-conflicting-aliases --distribution-id YourDistributionID --alias YourCNAME`` in your situation.

Hope this already helps.

Comment: I have not tried this command yet and I have deleted the distribution ID